# #includes in OMNeT++ Unit Tests

Tags: unit-testing, include, omnet++

I want to test my network with `opp_tool` in OMNeT++, but how do I include my own classes?

I wrote it into the `%includes:` part (for example my own message-subclass MyPacket.msg, so it is `#include "MyPacket_m.h"`) and included it to the root dir, but nothing works.

My test file:

```
%description:
Test file for MyPacket.msg

%global:

%file: test.msg
namespace @TESTNAME@;
    class MyPckt{
    int packetSizeInByte;
    ....
};


%includes:
#include <omnetpp.h>
#include "test_m.h"
#include "MyPacket_m.h"  // <---- this is the bad guy, how to include it?

%activity:

#define PRINT(X) ev << #X << ":" << X << endl

MyPckt job;

job.setPacketSizeInByte(255);
....


PRINT(job.getPacketSizeInByte());
....

%contains: stdout
job.getPacketSizeInByte():255
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you can include files by adding the absolute path (for example C:/omnettpp/workspace/some_projekt/myQueue.h). But there are still errors, although the code is right.

First I wrote the code in the testfile, everything is fine.
Second I wanted to include the code as a header, nothings fine :(

Still nobody got an idea?